# express.Router() get url route with optional parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I tried to get optional URL parameter using express.Router(), but it's not working.

If I use app.get, it is working correctly:

```
app.get('/videos/:category', function(req, res){
    // localhost:9876/videos/music
    debug(req.params); // This is working as expected
});
```

The only problem is when I try to use like this using express.Router().
I've tried like this:

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var videos = require('./routes/videos');

app.use('/videos/:category', videos);
```

**routes/videos.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:category', function(req, res){
    debug(req.params, req.params.category); // req.params is empty {}
});
module.exports = router;
```

I've also tried like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
        debug(req.params, req.params.category); // req.params is empty {}
});
```

How to solve this properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your both solutions you are getting the wrong route. In the first case it's `/videos/:category/:category`, in the second case - `/videos/:category/`. You need to move parameter to router.js `router.get` and remove it from app.js `app.use`:

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var videos = require('./routes/videos');

app.use('/videos', videos);
```

**routes/videos.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/:category', function(req, res){
    debug(req.params, req.params.category); // req.params is empty {}
});
module.exports = router;
```