# Using express.Router() with multiple urls and optional parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, routes

I am having trouble using express.Router() the way I wan to and am not sure what my issue is.  My problem is that when I make a GET request to the url ‘/api/zip’ or to ‘/api/zip/’ + zip, where zip is a numerical zip code, the only route that gets hit is ‘/‘, which in the example below logs ‘$$$$$$$$$$$$’.

When I take out the route for ‘/‘ in results_api.js, ‘made it to server.js’ gets logged, but I don’t get anything from results_api.js.  Let me know if I need to post more context code.  I am using an Angular front end, but I am assuming that since my request always gets to server.js (verified by ‘made it to server.js’ being logged), that my problem is within results_api.js.

I have used this routing method before and am not sure what is going wrong this time around.  How do I manage to hit routes.get('/zip/:zip... ?

In my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = express.Router();

//route to index.html
var assetFolder = Path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/');
routes.use(express.static(assetFolder));

//api routes
routes.use('/api/*', require(‘./api/results_api.js’), function(){ 
console.log('made it to server.js')});
```

My results_api.js file:

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
  console.log('$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$')

}); 

router.get('/zip', function(req, res){
  console.log(‘###################’)

}); 

router.get('/zip/:zip', function(req, res){
  console.log('%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%')

}); 

module.exports = router;
```

This question:

[express.Router() get url route with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36557792/express-router-get-url-route-with-optional-parameters)

Is close to mine, but there is no intermediate parameter ( in my case '/zip/' after '/api').  Is this indicative of what I am trying to do just being the wrong way to go about building my api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Call these handlers in reverse order. `/zip/:zip`, then `/zip`, then `/`.</strike>

Actually, the problem is this line:

```
routes.use('/api/*', require(‘./api/results_api.js’), function(){ 
console.log('made it to server.js')});
```

`/api/*` will "gobble up" anything after `/api/`, so your router will think it is called with `/`. Change this to:

```
routes.use('/api', require('./api/results_api.js'), function() { 
    console.log('made it to server.js')
});
```

Comment: I have actually tried that and the '/' is still the handler that gets used.  When I console log req.baseUrl inside of the '/' handler I get '/api/zip/78728', so I know the url is being constructed correctly.

Comment: Updated the answer after I had a chance to test this out :/

Comment: That was it!  Thanks man, I had actually tried ommitting ht '/*' before but I didn't have my handlers set up correctly and was at that point convinced that my handlers were the issue.